# When rock cracks at tectonic plate boundaries are the number and size of cracks reflected in seismographs?

Tags: earthquakes, seismology, predictability

Do seismographs become more complex (waves of different frequencies superimposed on one another) for higher magnitude earthquakes where I am guessing there would be a larger variety and number of cracks in stressed rocks for these earthquakes with more energy. If a seismograph becomes more complex for a given location over a number of months could this help predict large earthquakes?

Comment: the size of an earthquake does not correlate with the number of fractures.

Comment: @John I agree now. But the fractures will affect how sound energy is distributed at the surface on account of diffraction . A tough rock could build up a lot of pressure then suddenly fracture.A more fragile rock could gradually fracture in many places causing small earthquakes Perhaps the sound from an earthquake in one location could pass through cracks in another location and yield information about how stressed the rock is

Comment: I should have added information from a diffraction pattern.

Comment: I don't think you understand how fractures happen, you are working from a lot of false assumptions, you should try researching before you ask such a question.

Comment: The question has two parts that revolve around the concept of "damage zones": 1) are seismograms more complex? Fractures can lead to attenuation, can slow down seismic waves and act as waveguides, among other effects. So yes, sort of. 2) Can more heavily damaged fault zones reflect the potential for larger earthquakes? Perhaps. I am not sure I understand the question sufficiently well to answer - consider rewording. There has been extensive work to look at changes in the characteristics of fault zones (e.g. velocity) leading up to large earthquakes, with no particularly convincing precursors.